# Is there a way to Find then Replace on workspace using XCode

Tags: xcode

on Xcode there's a find in Workspace but there doesn't seem to be an option where you can also replace.

Comment: Did you look under the Find menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ***Search and Replace***

Command (⌘) + Option (⌥) + Shift (⇧) + F

### ***Search***

Command (⌘) + Shift (⇧) + F

Answer (score 1):

Press Option (⌥) + Shift (⇧) + Command (⌘) + F